# How do we give CSS styling to an li generated inside Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Not sure if this already has an answer. I have gone through around 4-5 SO questions and other resources unsuccessfully.

I have a small project. It has two lists. One list has hard coded values. The other list gets the items dynamically when users enters some text.

The problem is functionality is implemented, but the styling. I gave a `class` to the `ul` and applied the following style to the `li`

```
ul.myUL li { 
    width: 600px; 
    height: 85px; 
}.
```

The above code is not having any effect. However, if I apply the style just to `ul`, it affects both the un-ordered lists in the document. 
Is there any way to give the styling to the required part alone?

```css
ul.myUL li {
  cursor: pointer;
  position: relative;
  width: 500px;
  height: 75px;
}
```

```html
<ul id="myUL">
</ul>
```

Below is the code snippet:

Let me know if you need any more piece of code to resolve this.

Comment: change in CSS file `ul.myUL li` to this `#myUL li`

Comment: When refering an ID in css, use #, not '.'

Comment: My bad. Problem resolved. The power of a silly careless mistake!! Thanks a ton!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In ul you given id and accessing it in css in wrong way.
use this

```
 ul#myUL li {
    cursor: pointer;
    position: relative;
    width: 500px;
    height: 75px;
    }
```

Comment: Yep. Just realized.